# Rails/Activerecord use sort_by with multiple models and different attribute names for the sorting dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app and I want to include a list of orders, quotes, etc.  I currently include these in the view using.

```
  def dashboard
    rfqs = Rfq.all.where(is_active: true)
    rfis = Rfi.all
    orders = Order.all
    order_reminders = OrderReminders.all
    @posts = (rfqs + rfis + orders).sort_by(&:created_at)
  end
```

in the last line, I would like to use different attributes to sort the @posts with.
So every @post has a date to order by but with different names.

rfqs have a "due" attribute

rfis have a "date" attribute

orders have a "ship" attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@posts = (rfqs.to_a + rfis.to_a + orders.to_a).sort_by do |post|
  if post.is_a?(Rfq)
    post.due
  elsif
    ..
  else
    ..
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.  Is there a DRYer way to get the same result?  This seems a little bloated.

Comment: What's you definition of dry? Fitting on one line? Readability? You could use the database and make some thick common join table and sort that way. You could make a function that accepts posts and returns them sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a relatively new programmer. Just wondering if there was something more readable or shorter.